# Will turning a device on and off via power supply hurt it?

Tags: power-supply

I have an idea for a smart home set up, where I connect four electronic devices each into their own "smart" outlet, then use my phone to turn them all on at the same time with the touch of a button. It sounds cool, but I won't do it if there is any risks to the electronics. I suppose, in order for it to work I would have to leave the device "on" and then turn the smart socket on/off as desired.

**Question:** How safe is the above set up? Should I scrap the idea altogether, or should I proceed with some caveats in mind?

**Further Clarifications:**

- Electronic devices: my stereo system which is comprised of a DAC, amplifier, subwoofer and equalizer, all are powered. (I love my system, but it's really annoying having to turn on everything)
- Usage: I use it at least once a week (I know, I'm lazy and can't be bothered to labor over turning 4 devices on, even only once a week)
- Smart Socket - Zigby (x4)

If necessary I can provide my exact stereo brands and model specs, but I thought I could pose this question for the general case.

Comment: Have you ever seen your devices get broken due to blackout ?

Comment: If you turn off my satellite receiver that way, it can mess up the attached harddrive.  The satellite receiver is basically a PC with hardware to receive satellite TV.  Just like any PC, cutting off the power without first shutting down can cause problems with the disk.

Comment: @LongPham yes, yes that happens. Older washing machine motors are a known culprit of killing cellar light bulbs when the circuit breaker fires.

Answer (score 2):

The risk of damage depends on the individual design of the electronics, and can't be generally asserted.

I'd argue that consumer electronics should be expected to be relatively indifferent to sudden breakaway of supply current. Experience tells us that some devices are resilient, others not, for often very different reasons.

For example, JRE mentions that hard-drive containing systems might suffer. I think that might be an early 1990s phenomenon and mechanical damage to hard drives due to loss of supply would be a thing of the past. Still, hard drives contain data, and writing half of something will definitely break that something. It's a software problem to solve that issue (resilient file systems and broken file handling).

For inductive loads, a sudden change in current (e.g. due to a switch being flipped, moreso a relay being opened, a circuit breaker firing) will lead to a voltage spike. That's just physics. Whether or not that spike is dangerous to device itself, or others on the same phase, is up to the exact moment that breaking happened, the inductance, protective measurements on both the inductive load as well as other devices and sheer luck.

So, no general statement can be given. I'd argue that switch-mode power supplies these days are both relatively well protected against voltage dropouts and surges, and relatively low in inductivity. Noone but someone with time and a test stand can tell you how often you can externally switch your amplifier off and on without it taking damage – be it billions, thousands or just dozens of times, and the device manufacturer will of course never guarantee anything but switching off the device itself before removing it from supply.

I'm sorry, but you're on your own with this, and it's a basic task of personal risk assessment. I wouldn't worry too much if the cost of the devices in question are, divided by the amount of cycles you are pretty certain won't destroy them, is lower than let's say electricity costs of letting them run through.